# $watch listener being called once without change in expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller I have a variable called `datetime` which is updated by a timer every second. I need to do some work when the day changes, so I registered the following watcher:

```js
$scope.$watch("datetime | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'", function (newDate, oldDate) {
    console.log(newDate === oldDate);
}, true);
```

But this listener is being called with `newDate` being equal to `oldDate` in the beginning of the execution. Does anyone know what could be happening? The code that changes `datetime` is the following:

```js
var timeoutId;

function startTimer() {
    timeoutId = $timeout(tick, 1000);
    timeoutId.then(startTimer);
}

function stopTimer() {
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = undefined;
}

function tick() {
    $scope.datetime = new Date();
}

$scope.init = function () {
    startTimer();
}
```

`$scope.init()` is called by `ng-init`.

Comment: Did you check what the value of `datetime` is? It most likely is `undefined`...

Comment: By the way, for performance reasons, I'd move the "| date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'" part of your watch inside the function.  Right now that conversion is happening every `$digest`- when the `$watch` is checked.  But you really only need to convert when you actually use the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)** (emphasis mine):

> The listener is called only when the value from the current watchExpression and the previous call to watchExpression are not equal (**with the exception of the initial run**, see below).
>   [...]
>   After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called **when the result of watchExpression didn't change**. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

So, change your `$watch` like this:

```
$scope.$watch("datetime | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'", function (newDate, oldDate) {
    if (newData !== oldDate) {
        /* Value has changed: Do something useful */
        console.log(newDate === oldDate);
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

$watch triggered during the initial load as well, use a flag to avoid it.

```
var first = true;
$scope.$watch("datetime | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'", function (newDate, oldDate) {
    if(!first){
       console.log(newDate === oldDate);
    } else {
        first = false;
    }
}, true);
```